# Retrieve large number of records

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to retrieve a large number of data and print them in table. In one table I have around 5000 records that I need to print in table, and in one I have around 10000 records. 
I am using DataTable with pagination and time to print records in table is very slow. 
I have also tried to create stored procedure and timing is the same.

Any help or advice is very appreciated.

This is code I am using

```
$sql= "SELECT a.Id, a.Datum, a.Materijal, a.VrstaIzlaza, a.BrojIzlaza, a.Pocetno, a.Krajnje, a.Promet, b.OdjelNaziv, c.LokacNaziv
FROM jos_ib_promet_reprm_2014 a 
LEFT JOIN odjeli b ON a.Odjel=b.OdjelId  
LEFT JOIN sredstva c ON a.Poslovnica=c.LokacijaId order by a.Id desc"; 

$q = $conn->query($sql);

<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Materijal</th>
            <th>Izlaz</th>
            <th>Br. dokumenta </th>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Pocetno stanje</th>
            <th>Krajnje stanje</th>
            <th>Promet</th>
            <th>Odjel</th>
            <th>Poslovnica</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$r['Id'] ?></a> </td>
        <td>R-<?=$r['Materijal'] ?></td>
        <td><?=$r['VrstaIzlaza'] ?></td>
        <td><?=$r['BrojIzlaza']?></td>
        <td><?=$r['Datum'] ?></td>
        <td><?=$r['Pocetno'] ?></td>
        <td><?=$r['Krajnje'] ?></td>
        <td><?=$r['Promet'] ?></td>
        <td><?=$r['OdjelNaziv'] ?></td> 
        <td><?=$r['LokacNaziv'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use lazy loading technique, i.e fetch the data by AJAX only when you need to display them. The time consuming part comes from your long running MYSQL queries.

Comment: I don't see any "pagination" logic in your code... You're probably printing the full results table... :-(

Comment: use `LIMIT` in your SQL query to select no more than 50, maybe 100 records and implement pagination system. Reading few thousands at a time is bad idea

Comment: @Mysteryos is right. Also, if running the query in its eternity is crucial to your success, you could try optimizing it with the EXPLAIN keyword (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) for more details). (*i.e.* find the parts that take up most of your execution time and think of ways to improve them.)

Comment: I disagree with the comments above. It's not the query that's slow, but the time taken to render the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use some ajax as help. You print out kinda 20 records per page and as you go lower on the page you send another query to the server to load another 20 records. It's very efficient when you need to deal with large number of records.

Answer (score -1):

There is an optional flag in mysqli::query for just such an issue. It's called MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT. So your code should look as fallows.

```
$q = $conn->query($sql,MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
```